# IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, illegalstateexception

I am trying to remove an item from my `RecyclerView`, but I always get an error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

I am using `notifyDataSetChanged()`. How can I solve this?

**Here is my adapter code**

```
public class ListAdapters extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapters.MyViewHolder> {

    public ArrayList<String> tvdatalist;
    Context c;
    int pos;
    ListAdapters.MyViewHolder myViewHolder;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    int[] arr;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


        public EditText edttxt;
        public CheckBox cb;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            edttxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edttxt);
            cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }


    }

    public ListAdapters(Context c, ArrayList<String> tvdatalist) {
        this.c = c;
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.tvdatalist = tvdatalist;
        arr = new int[tvdatalist.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            arr[i] = 0;

        }


    }

    @Override
    public ListAdapters.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ListAdapters.MyViewHolder(this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_ittm, parent, false));
        //return new LandingPageAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(final ListAdapters.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        myViewHolder = holder;

        final String ShowsBean = tvdatalist.get(position);
        myViewHolder.edttxt.setText(ShowsBean);
        if (arr[pos] == 0) {
            myViewHolder.cb.setChecked(false);
            myViewHolder.edttxt.setKeyListener(null);
        } else {
            myViewHolder.cb.setChecked(true);
            myViewHolder.edttxt.setFocusable(true);
        }



        myViewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                    if (arr[position]==0){
                        arr[position]=1;
                    }else{
                        arr[position]=0;

                    }
                 notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tvdatalist.size();

    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick);
    }
}
```

Comment: This usually occurs when you are calling notify on bg thread. So just move notify to ui thread.

Comment: couldn't get you. can you please describe it?

Comment: Really can't think of another way to describe it. You wherever you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`(seems to be on background thread) from move it a UI thread. If you don't know the difference between background thread and UI thread then do some research.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Abbas said

> This usually occurs when you are calling notify on bg thread. So just move notify to ui thread

else you can use `notifyItemChanged(position);`

this will also worked as well.

Comment: i also use this in onbinholder class but still app crash and give this error

Answer (score 4):

You can also use runnable to make changes on UI thread.

```
recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

This will notify adapter changes on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

This problem shows when you are trying to update the recyclerview when it still inflating the item, try to move the notifyItemChanged(position), to where you are sure the item has been added to your view before calling the- method(notifyItemChanged(position));